# Java method overloading based on generics restrictions

Tags: java, generics, overloading

**Simplified description:**
I have method `process()`, which should do different things for objects which implement only `First` interface and different things for objects which implement `First` and `Second` interface at the same time. Naturally, an object implementing both interfaces still match to the `process()` method which requires implementing only the `First` interface. But fortunately the most specific overload is called as I need.

My question is, whether it's somewhere defined that this shall work on all Java implementations.

**Working sample:**

```
public class Main
{
  public interface Printer
  {
    void print ();
  }

  public interface Calculator
  {
    void calc ();
  }

  public static class MyPrinter implements Printer
  {
    @Override public void print ()
    {
      System.out.println ("MyPrinter");
    }
  }

  public static class MyPrintingCalculator implements Printer, Calculator
  {
    @Override public void print ()
    {
      System.out.println ("MyPrintingCalculator");
    }

     @Override public void calc ()
    {
      System.out.println ("Calculating");
    }
  }

  public static <T extends Calculator & Printer > void process (T something)
  {
    something.print ();
    something.calc ();
  }

  public static void process (Printer something)
  {
    something.print ();
  }

  public static void main (String args[])
  {
    final MyPrinter printer = new MyPrinter ();
    final MyPrintingCalculator calculator = new MyPrintingCalculator ();

    process (printer);
    process (calculator);
  }
}
```

Try on [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/Hy7yhg5Ptc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** yes, this behavior is well specified and hence, guaranteed to work across all Java implementations.

The choice of the most specific method is described in [JLS, §15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) as

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the *most specific* method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time error.

the latter section being sufficient to explain why `<T extends Calculator & Printer> void process(T something)` is more specific than `process(Printer something)`. Any valid argument to the former is a subtype of `Calculator` and `Printer`, hence, could be passed to `process(Printer)` without errors (but not the other way round).

The caveat here is that you have to declare the methods in a specific way to compile the overloaded declarations in the first place. Had you written `<T extends Printer & Calculator> void process(T something)`, the code wouldn’t compile.

The reason is given in [JLS, §4.6. Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6):

> The erasure of a type variable ([§4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.

So while being the same generic type, the erasure of `<T extends Calculator & Printer>` is `Calculator` but the erasure of `<T extends Printer & Calculator>` is `Printer`.

Had you used `<T extends Printer & Calculator> void process(T something)`, the erased method declaration would be `void process(Printer)` and conflict with the non-generic `void process(Printer)` method.

The declaration `<T extends Calculator & Printer> void process(T something)` is guaranteed to produce a method `process(Calculator)`, distinct from `process(Printer)` after type erasure. For completeness, had you both, a `void process(Printer)` and a `void process(Calculator)`, you could use this knowledge about type erasure to still create a distinct method for the generic variant, by using `<T extends Object & Calculator & Printer>`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Holger! This is really great answer I was looking for. I have even tried the version with `<T extends Printer & Calculator>` when I was first trying to achieve such behavior and I didn't understand why it works differently. This is true Java magic :-).

Answer (score 2):

answering the question you mentioned :

> My question is, whether it's somewhere defined that this shall work on all Java implementations.

so not all java version will support that solution , if you are working with **intellij-idea**  , you can specify the version of java to test that code on from `file -> project struct -> project language level` as in the image below :

[image]

starting from java 5 in 2004 , they introduced java generics and starting from java 6 in 2006 , they introduced the override in interfaces , major addition in java versions can be seen in the same window in **intellij-idea** like the next image :

[image]

so your code will work fine with any java implementation version 6 and above.

and here is image of result when running with java version 6 :

[image]

and the next one with java version 5:

[image]

and next one with java version 1.4 :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, good point, I need it working in Java 8+. Do you have idea where some specification for interface overloading can be found?

Comment: @Mi-La , maybe you could refer to oracle as Oracle Corporation is the current owner of the official implementation of the Java SE platform, so I don't know if that would help , but may be you could refer to their tutorials on their official website like [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a static method, you can introduce a new interface `Processable` that contains this method.

```
interface Processable<T> {
  void process(T something);
}
```

and then implement it with your aggregation

```
Processable<T> printerAndCalculator(Printer printer, Calculator calculator){
 return t -> {
  printer.print(t);
  calculator.calc(t);
 };
}
...
Processable<YourClass> printAndCalculate = printerAndCalculator(yourPrinter, yourCalculator);
printAndCalculate.process(actualParameter);
```

Note: I added the `T` argument to the `print()` and `calc()` methods because it was unused.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is not that it doesn't work, I only don't know why it works and whether it's suppose to work by language definition. And the static methods are used only for simplicity of the sample code.

Comment: @Mi-La What would not work? `T` is declared as `extends Calculator & Printer` in your method, so it will implement both interfaces and both methods are available. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: I'm asking how it is guaranteed that the overload with `<T extends Calculator & Pritner>` will be called for object which implements both interfaces. Because the overload with `Printer` (or even `<T extends Printer>`) would be also suitable.

Comment: @Mi-La No, they would not be suitable, it would violate the type parameter bounds: [A type variable with multiple bounds is a subtype of all the types listed in the bound](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html). You can read it as "a class implementing both `Printer` _and_ `Calculator`".

Comment: For version with `Printer & Calculator`, it's clear that both must be implemented. But an object implementing both is still well suitable for `process(Printer printer)`, since it's still `Printer`.